# Как обойти ошибку при определении продолжительности файла менее 10 секунд?

Tags: cmd, bat, ffmpeg

Есть **cmd** код которым определяю с помощью **ffmpeg**  продолжительность 5-ти штук видео фалов формата mp4.

Код:

```js
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do (
    for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('ffmpeg -i vidov_ska4ali_%%i.mp4 2^>^&1 ^| find "Duration"') do SET z=%%a
    set Z1=!Z:~0,2!
    set Z2=!Z:~3,2!
    set Z3=!Z:~6,2!

    if !Z1! LSS 10 (set Z1=0!Z1!)
    if !Z2! LSS 10 (set Z2=0!Z2!)
    if !Z3! LSS 10 (set Z3=0!Z3!)

    set /A vidov_ska4ali_%%i=!Z1! * 3600 + !Z2! * 60 + !Z3!
)
echo file "vidov_ska4ali_1.mp4" have 12 sec but displays !vidov_ska4ali_1! seconds
echo file "vidov_ska4ali_2.mp4" have 21 sec but displays !vidov_ska4ali_2! seconds
echo file "vidov_ska4ali_3.mp4" have 9 sec but displays !vidov_ska4ali_3! seconds
echo file "vidov_ska4ali_4.mp4" have 13 sec but displays !vidov_ska4ali_4! seconds
echo file "vidov_ska4ali_5.mp4" have 14 sec but displays !vidov_ska4ali_5! seconds
```

Но тут есть ошибка в определении продолжительности файла **vidov_ska4ali_3.mp4**. Она возникает т.к. файл имеет длину **9 сек**, то есть число состоящее из **одной цифры**. И соответственно в логе вот такое:
`Неправильное число. Числовые константы должны быть десятичными (17)
шестнадцатеричными (0x11),или восьмеричными (021).
file "vidov_ska4ali_1.mp4" have 12 sec but displays 12 seconds
file "vidov_ska4ali_2.mp4" have 21 sec but displays 21 seconds
file "vidov_ska4ali_3.mp4" have 9 sec but displays  seconds
file "vidov_ska4ali_4.mp4" have 13 sec but displays 13 seconds
file "vidov_ska4ali_5.mp4" have 14 sec but displays 14 seconds`

Answer (score 0):

так заработало. можно закрыть и считать ответом

```html
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do (
    for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('ffmpeg -i vidov_ska4ali_%%i.mp4 2^>^&1 ^| find "Duration"') do SET z=%%a
    
    set /A Z1=1!Z:~0,2!-100
    set /A Z2=1!Z:~3,2!-100
    set /A Z3=1!Z:~6,2!-100
 
    set /A vidov_ska4ali_%%i=!Z1! * 3600 + !Z2! * 60 + !Z3!
)
echo file "vidov_ska4ali_1.mp4" have 12 sec but displays !vidov_ska4ali_1! seconds
echo file "vidov_ska4ali_2.mp4" have 21 sec but displays !vidov_ska4ali_2! seconds
echo file "vidov_ska4ali_3.mp4" have 9 sec but displays !vidov_ska4ali_3! seconds
echo file "vidov_ska4ali_4.mp4" have 13 sec but displays !vidov_ska4ali_4! seconds
echo file "vidov_ska4ali_5.mp4" have 14 sec but displays !vidov_ska4ali_5! seconds
```